# Add caption div to image after expanding on rollover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, tooltip

I'm using this jQuery to expand images on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/bAHXJ/

Now I'd like to add a div for a caption, using the title, something like this:

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    $(this).each(function(){
          var title = this.title;
          $(this).after('<div class="caption">'+ title +'</div>');
      }); 
 });
```

When I add that the div appears behind the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/k62NY/

I tried .append instead of .after (still fuzzy on the difference) and nothing appeared.

How do I make the caption div appear below the expanded image, after the image is finished expanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your CSS slightly by adding a `.caption` class and `.hover` class.  I also modified your jQuery a lot to make it more readable (for me, haha, so that I could fix it) :

http://jsfiddle.net/k62NY/4/

Now ... I wasn't trying to make it look AMAZING, as that's your job.  Functionally though, it does as you wish.

Comment: I would note that the image title caption by default drives me nuts on this example ... so I would move the mechanism by which you pull your caption somewhere other than the title tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are positioned using absolute. So the div appears behind the image. If you want it to appear in front you will need to make a CSS change. Let me see if I can get a fiddle with what you want.

Your jquery is bad: change

```
var title = this.alt;
```

to

```
var title = $(this).alt;
```

Comment: Okay, I don't have time to do it for you, but I can get you started. I would wrap your image and your caption div inside another div absolutely positioned. Remove abs positioning from image. I updated my post with a jQuery fix that you need too.